# Stack pop method causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, stack, nullpointerexception

I have just implemented a loop to populate a player's hand (a queue) with cards (from a stack), but I am encountering a NullPointerException at LinkedStack.pop(). I haven't altered the provided LinkedStack code and I have checked that the deck is populated with elements, so I cannot immediately see where the NullPointerException is coming from. Below are my code segments and error output. If you require any other code, just let me know.

(SimpleUnoGame.java)

```
45    LinkedQueue<UnoCard> cardHand = new LinkedQueue<UnoCard>();
46    //draw cards for player
47    for(int j = 0; j < INITIAL_CARDS; j++) {
48        cardHand.enqueue(faceDownCards.pop());
49    }
50    newPlayer.setCards(cardHand);
51    playerCollection.enqueue(newPlayer);
```

(LinkedStack.pop())

```
43    T result = top.getElement();
44    top = top.getNext();
45    count--;
46    return result;
```

(Exception)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedStack.pop(LinkedStack.java:43)
    at SimpleUnoGame.<init>(SimpleUnoGame.java:48)
```

Here is the complete code, as requested:

(LinkedStack.java)

```
/**
 * Represents a linked implementation of a stack
 */

public class LinkedStack<T> implements StackADT<T> {
    //indicates number of elements stored
    private int count;  
    //pointer to top of stack
    private LinearNode<T> top; 

    /**
     * Creates an empty stack
     */
    public LinkedStack() {
        count = 0;
        top = null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack
     * @param element element to be pushed on stack
     */
    public void push(T element) {
        LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        temp.setNext(top);
        top = temp;
        count++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a reference to it
     * Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty
     * @return T element from top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException on pop from empty stack
     */
    public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("Stack");
        }

        T result = top.getElement();
        top = top.getNext();
        count--;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the element at the top of this stack
     * Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty
     * (the element is not removed from the stack)
     * @return T element on top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException on peek at empty stack  
     */
    public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("Stack"); 
        }

        return top.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise
     * @return boolean true if stack is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this stack
     * @return int number of elements in this stack
     */
    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this stack
     * @return String representation of this stack
     */
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        T result;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            result = top.getElement();
            output = output + result;
            top = top.getNext();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

(SimpleUnoGame.java)

```
public class SimpleUnoGame {

    private final int INITIAL_CARDS = 7;
    private LinkedQueue<UnoPlayer> playerCollection = new LinkedQueue<UnoPlayer>();
    private LinkedStack<UnoCard> faceUpCards = new LinkedStack<UnoCard>();
    private LinkedStack<UnoCard> faceDownCards = new LinkedStack<UnoCard>();
    private int cardCount = 0;

    public SimpleUnoGame(int numberOfPlayers, int highestRank) {
        //create cards and add to faceDownCards
        for(int i = 1; i <= highestRank; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                //blue cards
                UnoCard cardB = new UnoCard('B', i);
                faceDownCards.push(cardB);
                //green cards
                UnoCard cardG = new UnoCard('G', i);
                faceDownCards.push(cardG);
                //red cards
                UnoCard cardR = new UnoCard('R', i);
                faceDownCards.push(cardR);
                //yellow cards
                UnoCard cardY = new UnoCard('Y', i);
                faceDownCards.push(cardY);
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Cards: " + faceDownCards.toString());  //debug check

    //shuffle cards randomly
    shuffleCards(faceDownCards);

    System.out.println("Cards: " + faceDownCards.toString());  //debug check

    //create players and add to playerCollection
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        //ask for name
        String name = "Taylor";

        UnoPlayer newPlayer = new UnoPlayer(name);
        LinkedQueue<UnoCard> cardHand = new LinkedQueue<UnoCard>();

        //draw cards for player
        for(int j = 0; j < INITIAL_CARDS; j++) {
            cardHand.enqueue(faceDownCards.pop()); //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
        }

        newPlayer.setCards(cardHand);
        playerCollection.enqueue(newPlayer);
    }

    System.out.println("There are " + numberOfPlayers + " players in the game.");
    System.out.println(playerCollection.toString());  //debug check

    //draw one face up card
    faceUpCards.push(faceDownCards.pop());
}
```

Comment: Is ```faceDownCards``` populated?

Comment: `top` is `null` .  Without seeing the rest of your code, there's not much more we can tell you.

Comment: Clearly either `faceDownCards` *is* empty (despite what you say) or there *is* a problem with `LinkedStack`. You haven't given enough code -- or debugging output -- to help diagnose that problem.

Comment: `faceDownCards` is populated. When the stack is initialized, `top = null`, but after one element is added, `top = element`, and so on for new elements (as in any stack).

Comment: @lollercopter How many elements are in `faceDownCards`, and what is the value of `INITIAL_CARDS`? You might be popping off the end of the stack. Also, there should definitely be some kind of invariants check prior to calling `top.getElement()`, since it's pretty clear that something is not right.

Comment: Note that you're calling `faceDownCards.pop()` `INITIAL_CARDS` times for each player. How many players are there, what is `INITIAL_CARDS`, and how many elements does `faceDownCards` start out with?

Comment: The amount of cards in `faceDownCards` is set by the user in the main method. Right now, during testing, there are 32. `INITIAL_CARD` is 7, since there are 7 cards in each player's hand. I have set a check so that the number of players cannot exceed the total number of cards available. I don't think I'm popping off the end of the stack, since I used `linkedStack` in another program and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @lollercopter How many players are participating? 5 or more would take you off the end of the stack.

Comment: In this test I'm conducting right now, there is one player. The check is `if ((8*highestRank) > (10*numberOfPlayers))`. (This check was given to me in the specifications) The number of cards in a deck is 2 * 4 (number of colours) * highestRank (highest number).

Comment: @lollercopter Well, you're going to have to debug `LinkedStack` then, because something is going wrong there: `top` is `null` despite the `IsEmpty()` check passing.

Comment: That is very strange, considering it worked perfectly the last time I used it, and it hasn't changed since. But regardless, I'll still check the `LinkedStack` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **top** variable is null. How do you initialize it?

From your code sample it seems that you set **top** to null upon construction of your object and then only set it to something non-null when you push an item.

If that's the case, then it seems that you have not pushed something into the LinkedStack.

Although i must admit i have trouble figuring out the exact problem since you have only supplied bits of your code and it sort of doesn't make much sense.

**EDIT**

The method toString() modifies the **top** field which is supposed to hold the head of your queue. Calling the toString method should have no side-effects. Change it to this :

```
public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    T result;
    LinearNode<T> tempHead = top;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        result = tempHead.getElement();
        output = output + result;
        tempHead = tempHead.getNext();
    }

    return output;
}
```

I don't know who wrote this class for you but it's a rookie mistake. By calling toString() you are effectively emptying your queue.

Comment: This is ... not an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: @BrianRoach It sounds like an answer insofar if that it *is* the problem, then there really isn't more of an "answer" to give :( ... I'm not sure if it has to do with initializing vs. "running off the end" later though.

Comment: I suggest replacing _How do you initialize it?_ with _You should initialize it._ It's almost certainly correct, you might as well stand behind your diagnosis with conviction.

Comment: Is `top` not initialized as null when a stack is created, and assigned an element when an element is pushed? I have posted more code above for `LinkedStack`. The code has worked in the past, and I have not altered it.

Comment: check out the edited answer. Top is set to null upon construction, thus giving you a NullPointerException when trying to dereference it.

Comment: `Top` is a `LinearNode<T>`, which is another file given to me in the specifications that basically represents a node in the stack. I have pushed elements to the `faceDownCards` stack, and verified this by printing the stack before attempting to give each player their cards. I honestly do not see why it would be null...

Comment: you have to provide us with more code. The complete code if possible. There is a bug there somewhere.

Comment: Alright, I'll provide the complete code. Do you need the ADTs and exception files as well? I haven't touched those at all.

Comment: if the classes you use are third party library classes we can assume they are bug free. Just provide the code to your SimpleUnoGame.java class. Unless it's huge in which case start thinking refactoring

Comment: well me and my big mouth. The bug was in the LinkedStack class. Check out the fix.

Comment: It was in `toString()`? Wow, I never would've guessed... I'll need to talk to the person who wrote that method for us. Thank you so much for the help, it was much appreciated!

Comment: As a final note, why do you use your own implementation of a Queue and not the Java ones? LinkedList implements the Queue interface.